# HTML <xmp> tag! removing new paragraph

Tags: html, css

`<xmp><em>hi</em></xmp> how <xmp><em>are you?</em></xmp>`

Should render

`<em>hi</em> how <em> are you?</em>`

NOT

`<em>hi</em>`

`How`

`<em>are you?</em>`

The choice of sentence is not important. I need this for a table of HTML tags I'm making to help me with my coding, I need to include raw code, but it always seems to paragraph at the `<xmp>` tag! how do I stop this? Is there anyway to do this threw CSS?

Comment: You should escape the tags using HTML entities (`&lt;`)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

Answer (score 2):

The `xmp` element is rendered as a block by default, as described in the [rendering descriptions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#flow-content-0) in HTML5 CR. To override this, add the following to your style sheet:

```
xmp { display:inline; }
```